# Multivariable Calculus, Jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In the xy-plane, draw the region R bounded by the lines

$y = 1+x, \quad y= -1 +x, \quad y= -1-x, \quad y= 1-x$

Use double integral in rectangular and polar coordinates to find the area of R

you may want to use the integral: integral $(1/\sin\ u +\cos\ u)^2\ du =\sin\ u/\sin\ u+\cos\ u +C$ this information is provided for polar coordinates to be applied.

Comment: Your caps lock is on. Furthermore, what have you done already?

Comment: Why on earth would you use polar coordinates here?  In fact, why on earth would you even bother with a double integral at all, save for an exercise?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $u=y-x, v=y+x$ so as you were already given $$u|_{-1}^1,~~v|_{-1}^1$$ Now you can use the method [Change of Variables for Multiple Integrals](http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/change/change.html) , to find the area. Indeed we have to evaluate $$\int\int_Adxdy$$ According to the method above, we can do it by the following double integral instead: $$\int\int_{A'} J\left(\frac{x,y}{u,v}\right)dudv$$ wher in $$J=f_ug_v-f_vg_u,\\ y=g(u,v)=\frac{u+v}2,~~x=f(u,v)=\frac{v-u}2,~~-1\leq u\leq1,~~-1\leq v\leq1$$ The first image is $A$ and the second is $A'$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: limits for integral polar coordinates

Comment: for rectangular coordinates there is no function given over which we can evaluate the double integral. so i have to use integral dx dy and for polar r dr dtheta. correct me if im wrong

Comment: you may want to use the integral:  integral (1/sinu +cosu)^2 du =sinu/sinu+cosu   +C this information is provided.

Comment: @ Babak Sorouh i have added some extra information

Comment: i have managed to do the questions by using y = mx + c and substituting y=r sin theta and x= r cos theta

Comment: @ Babak Sorouh. I used the above method you gave in rectangular coordinates and it works fine. In polar coordinates we have to use the general equation for line in polar form. which is r = c/sinu - m cosu. got same answer as in rectangular coordinates.

Comment: @Avinesh: You have to evaluate $$4\int_{r=0}^{r=\frac{1}{\sin(t)+\cos(t)}}\int_{t=0}^{t=\pi/2}rdrdt$$. I put $4$ becuse the area is a symmetric one.

Comment: integral of (1/sinu +cosu)^2 du = sinu/sinu + cosu according to trig identities. the answer to be multiplied by 4.

Comment: @Avinesh: It is $4\times\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{2(\sin(t)+\cos(t))^2}$.

Comment: yes it does make sense now.my final aanswer comes to 2 is it correct.

Comment: integral 1/(2 (cos(t)+sin(t))^2) dt = (sin(t))/(2 (sin(t)+cos(t)))+constant with limiits the answer comes to 2

Comment: @Avinesh: Indeed, it is $4\times\frac{-1}{2(1+\tan(x))}$. Now put the limits.